# Missing playback device

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a new docking station (Caldigit TB4) connected through TB4/UBS4 to my laptop (Dell XPS 9310). There are speakers connected through the docking statation, and they work well with other laptops.

When I run `aplay -l` I see the the device listed

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Rear [CalDigit TS4 Audio - Rear], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Still, nothing shows up in the list of Playback Devices, even when showing all inactive devices. I share the screenshot from the Audio settings panel; the output from `pacmd list-sinks` is aligned

[image]

I tried manually loading the module with `pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:2`  but I get a failure "Failure: Module initialization failed"

Anything else I can try to get the playback device?